# Generalize a sql query to accomodate full and incremental extract

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a the following query :

```
select * from table where createddate>='03-Feb-2020' and createddate<'04-Feb-2020'
```

The above query will give me incremental count for a single day.

How do i generalize the above query so that i can get the entire historical data/full dump without changing the where clause.

For example:

```
select * from table where createddate>='VARIABLE1' and createddate<'VARIABLE2'
```

Is there a way that without changing the schema of the sql query i can just pass in different values for the createddate to get the full dump?

Comment: you can use a function that will take variable1 and variable2 as parameters

Comment: Why not use '1000-01-01' and  '9999-12-31'?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I want to generalize the query so that on the first day some wrapper will pass 2 variables that would run a full dump and from 2nd day it would pass different variables(currentdate -1 and currenddate) to get the incremental dump

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
where createddate >= '1000-01-01' and createddate < '9999-12-31'
```

Note that dates in MySQL must be formated as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Yes somewhere on similar line but how to automate it? How to let my program know that first day pass the extreme dates on both ends and then from the 2nd day pass the currentdate-1 and currentdate. Is there a condition of 1=1 i can leverage somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `group by`?

```
select date(createddate), count(*)
from table 
group by date(createddate);
```

This returns the count for each day.